# Using a parameter in JavaFX methods

Tags: java, javafx

I am building an JavaFX application and am want to access values passed as an argument within the JavaFX UI. For some reason, I am unable to access these values in all the methods except the base method launchForm. Here is what my code looks like.

```
public class FormBuilder extends Application {

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * @see javafx.application.Application#start(javafx.stage.Stage)
     * Scene scene
     *      Group root
     *          BorderPane borderPane
     *              TabPane tabPane
     *                  Tab stocksTab
     *                      BorderPane stockTabBorderPane
     *                          GridPane gridPane
     *          
     */

    private Stocks stockData = new Stocks();
    private int size;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        stage.setTitle("Stock Manager");
        Group root = new Group();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 1024, 800, Color.WHITE);

        TabPane tabPane = new TabPane();
        BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane();
        BorderPane stockTabBorderPane = new BorderPane();

        Tab stocksTab = new Tab("Stocks");

        stockTabBorderPane.setTop(this.addHBox());
        stockTabBorderPane.setCenter(this.createGridPane());

        stocksTab.setContent(stockTabBorderPane);
        tabPane.getTabs().add(stocksTab);

        borderPane.setCenter(tabPane);

        borderPane.prefHeightProperty().bind(scene.heightProperty());
        borderPane.prefWidthProperty().bind(scene.widthProperty());

        root.getChildren().add(borderPane);


        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();


    }

    private HBox addHBox() {
        HBox hbox = new HBox();
        hbox.setPadding(new Insets(15, 12, 15, 12));
        hbox.setSpacing(10);
        hbox.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #336699;");

        Button buttonCurrent = new Button("Current");
        buttonCurrent.setPrefSize(100, 20);

        Button buttonProjected = new Button("Projected");
        buttonProjected.setPrefSize(100, 20);
        hbox.getChildren().addAll(buttonCurrent, buttonProjected);

        return hbox;
    }

    private GridPane createGridPane() {

        GridPane gridPane = new GridPane();

        gridPane.setLayoutX(39);
        gridPane.setLayoutY(131.0);
        gridPane.setAlignment(Pos.TOP_CENTER);
        gridPane.setVgap(5.0);
        gridPane.setHgap(10.0);

        gridPane.add(new Label("Active"), 1,1);
        gridPane.add(new Label("Stock"), 2, 1);
        gridPane.add(new Label("Symbol"), 3, 1);
        gridPane.add(new Label("LPP"), 4, 1);
        gridPane.add(new Label("LPP"), 5, 1);
        gridPane.add(new Label("HPP"), 6, 1);
        gridPane.add(new Label("LTP"), 7, 1);

        System.out.println(this.size);
        for(int v=2;v < this.stockData.getStocks().size()+2; v++) {
            gridPane.add(new CheckBox(), 1, v);
            gridPane.add(new Label("Amazon"), 2, v);
            gridPane.add(new TextField (), 3,v);
            gridPane.add(new TextField (), 4,v);
            gridPane.add(new TextField (), 5,v);
            gridPane.add(new TextField (), 6,v);
            gridPane.add(new TextField (), 7,v);

        }

        return gridPane;
    }

    public void launchForm(Stocks stockData) {
        this.stockData = stockData;
        this.size = stockData.getStocks().size();
        System.out.println(stockData.getStocks().size());
        System.out.println(stockData.getStocks().get(0).getSector());
        launch();
    }
}
```

Now the issue is that when I try and access any value under the `stockData` object within the `createGridPane` method, the values are not available.

Examples are

`this.stockData.getStocks().size()` gives the value of 0 in the `createGridPane` method. But it gives a value of 2 in the `launchForm` method.

Again there are other values like

```
 this.stockData.getStocks().get(0).getSector()
```

which returns the value `"Retail"` in the `launchForm` method. But when I try to access the same in a different method in the same class, I get an exception.

Can someone please help me here?

Comment: Where are you calling `launchForm` from? And why are you calling `launch()` from inside that method? [`launch()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Application.html#launch-java.lang.String...-) starts the application: surely the application is already started at that point. I think you must have fundamentally misunderstood the JavaFX lifecycle: see the [`Application` docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Application.html)

Comment: I think you probably need to include more information in this question as to what you're doing, and how you have structured your application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In JavaFX you should basically consider the `Application` subclass, and in particular its `start()` method, to be the entry point of the application. The application lifecycle is described in the [`Application` Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Application.html), but in brief the JavaFX launch process is initiated either by calling one of the static `Application.launch(...)` methods, or (using the Oracle JDK) by launching the JVM and specifying an `Application` subclass as the main class (even if it doesn't have a `main` method).

The launch process then:

1. starts the JavaFX toolkit
2. creates a new instance of the `Application` subclass
3. invokes `init()` on the `Application` subclass (the default implementation is a no-op)
4. starts the FX Application Thread
5. invokes `start()` on the `Application` subclass, executing it on the FX Application Thread.

Despite being invoked on different threads, `start()` is guaranteed not to be invoked until `init()` has completed.

From the code you posted, it must be the case that you are instantiating your `FormBuilder` class somewhere else, and calling `launchForm(...)` on that instance. When you call `launch()` from there, that creates a second instance and invokes `start()` on it, as described above. So of course the fields that you set on the instance on which `launchForm(...)` is called will not be set on the instance on which `start(...)` is called.

You should refactor your code so that either `FormBuilder` is the entry point to the application, or make `FormBuilder` not be an `Application` subclass and create a new entry point that instantiates and uses it. It appears you have some background work which loads data: this should be a separate class which should not be the entry point. So the first refactoring would look like:

```
// class that reads data and encapsulates it as a Stocks object

public class StockDataAccessor {

    // ...

    public Stocks getStocks() {
        // ...
    }

}
```

Then `FormBuilder` looks like:

```
public class FormBuilder extends Application {

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * @see javafx.application.Application#start(javafx.stage.Stage)
     * Scene scene
     *      Group root
     *          BorderPane borderPane
     *              TabPane tabPane
     *                  Tab stocksTab
     *                      BorderPane stockTabBorderPane
     *                          GridPane gridPane
     *          
     */

    private Stocks stockData ;
    private int size;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

        StockDataAccessor stockDataAccessor = new StockDataAccessor();
        stockData = stockDataAccessor.getStocks();

        stage.setTitle("Stock Manager");
        Group root = new Group();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 1024, 800, Color.WHITE);

        TabPane tabPane = new TabPane();
        BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane();
        BorderPane stockTabBorderPane = new BorderPane();

        Tab stocksTab = new Tab("Stocks");

        stockTabBorderPane.setTop(this.addHBox());
        stockTabBorderPane.setCenter(this.createGridPane());

        stocksTab.setContent(stockTabBorderPane);
        tabPane.getTabs().add(stocksTab);

        borderPane.setCenter(tabPane);

        borderPane.prefHeightProperty().bind(scene.heightProperty());
        borderPane.prefWidthProperty().bind(scene.widthProperty());

        root.getChildren().add(borderPane);


        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();


    }

    private HBox addHBox() {
        HBox hbox = new HBox();
        hbox.setPadding(new Insets(15, 12, 15, 12));
        hbox.setSpacing(10);
        hbox.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #336699;");

        Button buttonCurrent = new Button("Current");
        buttonCurrent.setPrefSize(100, 20);

        Button buttonProjected = new Button("Projected");
        buttonProjected.setPrefSize(100, 20);
        hbox.getChildren().addAll(buttonCurrent, buttonProjected);

        return hbox;
    }

    private GridPane createGridPane() {

        GridPane gridPane = new GridPane();

        gridPane.setLayoutX(39);
        gridPane.setLayoutY(131.0);
        gridPane.setAlignment(Pos.TOP_CENTER);
        gridPane.setVgap(5.0);
        gridPane.setHgap(10.0);

        gridPane.add(new Label("Active"), 1,1);
        gridPane.add(new Label("Stock"), 2, 1);
        gridPane.add(new Label("Symbol"), 3, 1);
        gridPane.add(new Label("LPP"), 4, 1);
        gridPane.add(new Label("LPP"), 5, 1);
        gridPane.add(new Label("HPP"), 6, 1);
        gridPane.add(new Label("LTP"), 7, 1);

        System.out.println(this.size);
        for(int v=2;v < this.stockData.getStocks().size()+2; v++) {
            gridPane.add(new CheckBox(), 1, v);
            gridPane.add(new Label("Amazon"), 2, v);
            gridPane.add(new TextField (), 3,v);
            gridPane.add(new TextField (), 4,v);
            gridPane.add(new TextField (), 5,v);
            gridPane.add(new TextField (), 6,v);
            gridPane.add(new TextField (), 7,v);

        }

        return gridPane;
    }

    // for non-JavaFX aware environments (like your IDE...)
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Then launching `FormBuilder` as your main class will do what you need.

---

If you want to factor the application entry point out of the `FormBuilder` class entirely, the alternative refactoring (which is pretty similar) looks like:

```
public class FormBuilder {

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * @see javafx.application.Application#start(javafx.stage.Stage)
     * Scene scene
     *      Group root
     *          BorderPane borderPane
     *              TabPane tabPane
     *                  Tab stocksTab
     *                      BorderPane stockTabBorderPane
     *                          GridPane gridPane
     *          
     */

    private Stocks stockData ;
    private int size;

    private Group root ;

    public FormBuilder() {

        StockDataAccessor stockDataAccessor = new StockDataAccessor();
        stockData = stockDataAccessor.getStocks();

        root = new Group();

        TabPane tabPane = new TabPane();
        BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane();
        BorderPane stockTabBorderPane = new BorderPane();

        Tab stocksTab = new Tab("Stocks");

        stockTabBorderPane.setTop(this.addHBox());
        stockTabBorderPane.setCenter(this.createGridPane());

        stocksTab.setContent(stockTabBorderPane);
        tabPane.getTabs().add(stocksTab);

        borderPane.setCenter(tabPane);

        borderPane.prefHeightProperty().bind(scene.heightProperty());
        borderPane.prefWidthProperty().bind(scene.widthProperty());

        root.getChildren().add(borderPane);



    }

    public Parent getView() {
        return root ;
    }

    private HBox addHBox() {
        HBox hbox = new HBox();
        hbox.setPadding(new Insets(15, 12, 15, 12));
        hbox.setSpacing(10);
        hbox.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #336699;");

        Button buttonCurrent = new Button("Current");
        buttonCurrent.setPrefSize(100, 20);

        Button buttonProjected = new Button("Projected");
        buttonProjected.setPrefSize(100, 20);
        hbox.getChildren().addAll(buttonCurrent, buttonProjected);

        return hbox;
    }

    private GridPane createGridPane() {

        GridPane gridPane = new GridPane();

        gridPane.setLayoutX(39);
        gridPane.setLayoutY(131.0);
        gridPane.setAlignment(Pos.TOP_CENTER);
        gridPane.setVgap(5.0);
        gridPane.setHgap(10.0);

        gridPane.add(new Label("Active"), 1,1);
        gridPane.add(new Label("Stock"), 2, 1);
        gridPane.add(new Label("Symbol"), 3, 1);
        gridPane.add(new Label("LPP"), 4, 1);
        gridPane.add(new Label("LPP"), 5, 1);
        gridPane.add(new Label("HPP"), 6, 1);
        gridPane.add(new Label("LTP"), 7, 1);

        System.out.println(this.size);
        for(int v=2;v < this.stockData.getStocks().size()+2; v++) {
            gridPane.add(new CheckBox(), 1, v);
            gridPane.add(new Label("Amazon"), 2, v);
            gridPane.add(new TextField (), 3,v);
            gridPane.add(new TextField (), 4,v);
            gridPane.add(new TextField (), 5,v);
            gridPane.add(new TextField (), 6,v);
            gridPane.add(new TextField (), 7,v);

        }

        return gridPane;
    }

}
```

and then create an entry point:

```
public class StockApp extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        FormBuilder formBuilder = new FormBuilder();
        Scene scene = new Scene(formBuilder.getView(), 1024, 800, Color.WHITE);
        stage.setTitle("Stock Manager");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: This helped and I was able to fix the issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You're invoking `Application.launch` in the `launchForm` instance method and expect it to use the instance this method is invoked for as application class.

The JavaFX launch does not work this way however.

If `Application.launch` is called, a *new* instance of the class the method is invoked from is created by the `launch` method itself and it is this new instance that is used with `init` and `start`.

The easiest way to fix this would be, if you could create the `Stocks` in the `init` or `start` (possibly passing some Strings as parameters to `launch`).

Otherwise you need some other way to communicate with the newly created instance of the `Application` subclass, e.g. `static` members...

Comment: It just looks like this should not be an `Application` subclass at all, and should be a `Stage` subclass (or should have a reference to a `Stage`). Then just replace `launch()` with `show()`.

Comment: @James_D: If the OP got to the point where the `start` method is invoked on the new instance, the platform has not been launched and any attempt to show the `Stage` would inevitably fail...

Comment: That is true. But it just seems like the lifecycle is all wrong here. Clearly some other code is being executed prior to calling `launchForm`. There really shouldn't be anything prior to that; all startup code should be in `init()` or `start()`, except in really unusual circumstances. (Which is similar to what you're saying with your penultimate paragraph.) So the "other code" should be the `Application` subclass, and this class should be something else. I guess I mean that there are more structural problems here than the code which the OP has posted.

Comment: So the entry into the application is from the MyStocks class. MyStocks calls a few methods which reads data from a json file and converts it into a Stocks java object. In the MyStocks class, I have section of code which calls the launchForm method and passes the Stocks object as an argument.

FormBuilder formBuilder = new FormBuilder();
formBuilder.launchForm(stockData);

Comment: @ngnear Just move all that functionality to the `start()` method. (Or move it to a separate class and invoke it from the `start()` method.) Make the `Application` subclass you have the entry to the application and just call `launch()` from `main()` in the usual way.

Comment: @James_D So basically you are asking me to move the entry point to the program to the FormBuilder class file. Currently I have it in a different class where I prepare the data and am trying to pass it to the FormBuilder class. Did I understand that correctly?

Comment: @ngnear Yes. In JavaFX you should really think of the `start()` method (or `init()` method if you have one) as the entry point of the application. (Note that if you're running under Oracle JDK you don't even need a `main()` method. Strange but true.)

Comment: Thank you @James_D. I will refactor my code and let the group know if it worked.